# Jersey custom ExceptionMapper not called on 400 Bad Request (when validation fails)

Tags: spring, jersey-2.0

I'm using Jersey with Spring for web services. For catching exceptions and formatting the response sent to the caller I have added an implementation of ExceptionMapper.

Though it is being called when I explicitly throw an exception from within the controller, but when the json field validation fails the exception mapper is not called and the response sent is **may not be null (path = checkNotification.arg0.tyres, invalidValue = null)
**

```
@Provider
public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception Mapper !!!");
        return Response.status(404).entity(ex.getMessage()).type("application/json").build();
    }
}


<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>
                        com.help.rest.controller,
                        com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json
                </param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
                    <param-value>com.help.filter.FeatureRegistration</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>jersey.config.beanValidation.enableOutputValidationErrorEntity.server</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Jersey Version is 2.22.1
Spring Version is 4.2.4

I made it work by changing

```
 @Provider
    public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

        @Override
        public Response toResponse(Throwable ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception Mapper !!!");
            return Response.status(404).entity(ex.getMessage()).type("application/json").build();
        }
    }
```

to

```
 @Provider
    public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {

        @Override
        public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception Mapper !!!");
            return Response.status(404).entity(ex.getMessage()).type("application/json").build();
        }
    }
```

Though I'm able to catch the exception I am not getting the exact class and field which failed the constraint.

---

**Resolved** 
Found a Set containing all the required fields in ContraintViolationException, could be accessed using ex.getConstraintViolations()

Comment: have you registered your exception mapper?

Comment: The mapper for bean validation handles the exception. Only one mapper can be used. I imagine this is what you want, since you enabled the error entity output. If not you can add your own mapper for ConstraintViolationException to override the one used by Jersey

Comment: Yes I have registered the Exception Mapper class.

Comment: I get it working by changing public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable>  to public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> ... but now the question is how to get the exact field which failed the constraint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

made it work by changing

```
 @Provider
    public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

        @Override
        public Response toResponse(Throwable ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception Mapper !!!");
            return Response.status(404).entity(ex.getMessage()).type("application/json").build();
        }
    }
```

to

```
 @Provider
    public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {

        @Override
        public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception Mapper !!!");
            return Response.status(404).entity(ex.getMessage()).type("application/json").build();
        }
    }
```

To get the exact exception details, like which field failed the constraint use ConstraintViolationException's getConstraintViolations(). This method provides a set for all the constraint violations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register it:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(HelloWorldResource.class);

        /** you need to add ExceptionMapper class as well **/
        s.add(GenericExceptionMapper.class)
        return s;
    }
}
```